# AlarmManager inflates layout

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have an AlarmManager in my MainActivity that is used to check a website and create a notification if certain conditions are true.

The AlarmManger uses pending intent > broadcast receiver in a separate class. That broadcast receiver class then calls a third activity that executes the code to check the website and process the results, all in the background while the app is not open.

The problem is that when the alarm event fires it actually opens the app's main layout. I don't specifically create or inflate this layout anywhere but in the MainActivity.

I think the issues is arising when my Broadcast Receiver calls the new intent. I think the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK is what is causing the layout to open. I don't have any special launch modes specified in my manifest so I don't think that could be the problem.

My question is, is there a way for me to start this intent in the background from the broadcast receiver without triggering a layout to show? Can I add a different flag or something in the manifest?

```
package alert.wow.onlinealert;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmReceiver1 extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
System.out.println("Timed Signal received by AlarmReceiver");
   try {

 Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Jrequest.class);
intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent1);       
    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());

    } 
    }
 }
```

The end goal here is to have the AlarmReceiver run silently in the background once an hour and then send the notification if the criteria are met, the app itself should rarely need opened.

I'd be happy to post more code if its helpful.

Thanks,
  Chris

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Service instead of Activity, here is a working [example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Alarm/src/com/commonsware/android/syssvc/alarm) by Mark Murphy

Hope this helps, Yaron

Comment: Thanks for the links! I'm pretty new to all of this. Could you please provide a bit of context for those java files? I assume I need to use them all since they seem to link to each other but I'm not sure exactly what purpose each one serves or who I make the initial hop into them. Also, in using those will the service continue to execute even while the phone is asleep or will the process wait and run on wake?

Comment: Here is a [link](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/SystemServices/Alarm) to the complete project which you can download and then import to Eclipse.